# How do I correct the following attribute error?

Tags: django, python-2.7, oracle11g

I'm a newbie in Django and I don't know how to solve this.

context:

- 1.- Django with oracle 11g.
- 2.- in cmd *python manage.py syncdb*
- 3.- the message error is:

I read another `'attributeError'` with the `'lower'`, but i can't found the archive with `'nltk.pos_tag(clean)'` ([Python AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061369/python-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-lower))

My models.py is a normal models and the error is in a driver (i think so). In a official website of Django I see that we use this with oracle (the single quote):

(for example)

```
*class Meta:
    db_table ='"desactivacion_empresa"',* 

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\
introspection.py", line 64, in table_name_converter
return name.lower()
```

the line 64 of introspection is:

```
*def table_name_converter(self, name):
    "Table name comparison is case insensitive under Oracle"
    return name.lower()*
```

really, I don't know what to do...

---

EDIT
a complete model for example:

```
class desactivacion_empresa(models.Model):
    id_desactivacion = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    empresa_involucrada = models.ForeignKey(empresa_contacto)
    fecha_desactivacion = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now = True,
        blank = False,
        null = False
    )
    fecha_activacion = models.DateTimeField(
        blank = False,
        null = True
    )
    motivo_desactivacion = models.TextField(
        blank = False,
        null = False
    )
    class Meta:
        db_table ='"desactivacion_empresa"',
        verbose_name = 'Desactivación de empresa',
        verbose_name_plural = 'Desactivaciones de las empresas'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fecha_desactivacion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a stray `,` after the `db_table` attribute. Change it to

```
class Meta:
    db_table = "desactivacion_empresa" 
    #                                 ^ remove the stray ,
```

Also, get rid of the extra quotes.

The `,` makes the string being interpreted as a tuple

Demo

```
>>> x = "a",
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> y = "a"
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Edit:

Based on your edit, just change your class Meta to

```
class Meta:
    db_table = "desactivacion_empresa"
    verbose_name = 'Desactivación de empresa'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Desactivaciones de las empresas'
```

Comment: was as example. The complete meta is:
 class Meta:
  db_table ='"desactivacion_empresa"',
  verbose_name = 'Desactivación de empresa',
  verbose_name_plural = 'Desactivaciones de las empresas'

Comment: for the single quote, i read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/

Comment: no.. either of the quotes are needed. Also meta attributes are one per line, and not comma delimited...

Comment: without single coma, the table name is nameRandomNumbers . and yes, one per line (the comment show in this form :c )

Comment: I dont understand you. Can you edit the question with your exact model ? (atleast the model definition and the meta attributes) ?

Comment: Edit with a complete model. The others are very similar to this

Comment: Yeah.. just change the `class Meta` like the edit in the answer. Similar edits to whereever this is the case.

Comment: it's worked! but, i have another error -.-
Why in meta we don't use the comma?